# Im have a Typescript Problem which already asked few persons, and many got solution in upgrade version. But not Working for me

Tags: reactjs, typescript, configuration, redux-toolkit

D:/.../../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts
TypeScript error in D:/.../.../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(1,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005

> 1 | import type { Reducer, ReducersMapObject, Middleware, Action, AnyAction, StoreEnhancer, Store, Dispatch, PreloadedState, CombinedState } from 'redux';
> |             ^
> 2 | import type { EnhancerOptions as DevToolsOptions } from './devtoolsExtension';
> 3 | import type { ThunkMiddlewareFor, CurriedGetDefaultMiddleware } from './getDefaultMiddleware';
> 4 | import type { DispatchForMiddlewares, NoInfer } from './tsHelpers';

I have tried mostly solutions like upgrade typescript which is 4.4.4 and node 14

this is Package.json   I can share further information if need

```
 {
  "name": "project9a-shopping-cart-with-redux",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@wellyshen/use-web-animations": "^0.5.5",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any other messages? Please share all the ooutput. I can see there are problems in your dist folder, try: `rm -rf node_modules/` and `npm install`. You will have to make sure that all your dependencies work well with the typescript version, so you might have to update some other dependencies too.

Answer (score 0):

H3AR7B3A7   yes you guess right, I were downloaded someone code from github and run npm install so that specific software and dependencies auto install to them, But somehow in my PC typescript 4.4.4 was globally install and code on github was 3.7.7 but after npm intall i'm tried to manually update package.json 4.4.4 again and run npm install again even it was showing with tsc -v that this folder have 4.4.4 but I hope internally system was mixing things up.
So I try same process in another folder but this time before run npm install i'm changed 3.7.7 to 4.4.4 and run npm install, work fine after that

Comment: I confirm mismatch with Typescript version can cause this error